# ldapsearch - filtering ou in dn

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I understand you can't simply filter on `dn`, but I have something like this:

`dc=lvl3,dc=lvl2,dc=lvl1`, and someone could have a `dn` like this:
`CN=Last, First,OU=ou1,OU=retired,OU=ou1,DC=lvl3,DC=lvl2,DC=lvl1`.

Is there a way I can filter results for those who do not have 'retired' in any ou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not as an LDAP filter.

You could of course do a search and then sort on the CLient-side.

Generally organization of "characteristics" of users should be done using Attributes and not by the Directory Structure.

Something like:

- employeeType=Active
- employeeType=Retired
- employeeType=etc

To avoid these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but it depends on the server's LDAP implementation.

There *is* a filter syntax which allows matching against DN attributes (in addition to entry attributes):

```
(ou:dn:=Retired)
```

*(Within the LDAP specification this is known as the 'dnAttributes' field, part of the 'extensibleMatch' filter type. See [RFC 4511 section 4.5.1.7.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5.1.7.7))*

**Not all** directory servers support this. For example, OpenLDAP handles it correctly, but Active Directory (MS AD and Samba) will ignore it, behaving as if you used `(ou=Retired)` instead.

If your server supports this, then a negative match is simply done by wrapping the filter in `(!(...))` as you would normally do.

However, in other cases you should either a) use a custom attribute, or b) perhaps check for membership in a global "Active employees" group or something similar.